# Vue print page with original styles

Tags: css, vue.js, printing, styles

I have application and I want to have print button that print my page, but with original style from css. Already I have button that evoke function    `window.print()`. Also i have `print.scss` with styles

```
    @media print {
     header {display:none;}
     footer {display:none;}
     button {visibility: hidden;}
    }
```

Problem is that I want to have original styles from my styles files (there are many).

[image: original style]

[image: print version]

(I cut off buttons on purpose.)

Comment: I think you need to customize media print.scss to get the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I found solution, it was just no background colors attached. In media query for print I just added this:
    `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;`